# Python: List to Hex

Tags: python, hex

I am writing a small forensics python app and I am having trouble converting a List entry to Hex.  I have tried the encode/decode methood but get bogus conversions or odd-length string Type Errors.  I have pasted the code below, and as you can see I need the address in hex, so I can add the count to it.

```
def location_finder(line):
count = 0
temp = line.split(' ') #3 Tokenizes first element, by first space
address = str(temp[0].split(':')) # Take's : off of first element(address)
print address, "dog"
address = address.decode("hex")
print address, "cat"
#print temp[0]
line_address = temp[0].upper()
for addy in temp:

    if addy == "ffd8":
        return (address+count)
    if addy == "ffd9":
        return (address+count)

count = count + 1
```

Comment: Your code formatting is quite broken. Could you fix this, please?

Comment: What do you think "address = address.decode("hex")" does?  Why did you write this?

Comment: the code formatting looks fine to me ndim.  Anyway S.Lott, I write this to decode the string address into hex.

Comment: Where did you read about the "hex" codec?  Can you provide a link or a reference?  This is an odd thing to guess at.  I'm wondering what caused you to make this leap.

Comment: @Recursion. The formatting is broken because you have used tabs instead of spaces for indenting. If you had posted an List entry that you are trying to parse instead of just broken code you would have had several answers within a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hex` function converts integers to their hexadecimal representation:

```
>>> a = 123
>>> hex(a)
'0x7b'
```

Comment: I tried that already and moved on due to this error,  TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex

Comment: @Recursion: If you find an error, try to find out about the cause; randomly trying other methods is not going to help you in the long run.

Comment: I don't have paranormal powers, but I suspect you're trying to pass a string to `hex`.  Try `hex(int(a))` or post some actual code.